# Recursive function to verify Matrix is Symmetric in C

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I am just working on a recursive function to verify if a matrix is symmetric or not. The matrix must be square and I am considering max n = 20. I could develop the function:

```
int verifySymmetric(int m[20][20], int i, int j, int n) {
    if (!((n == i) || (n == j))) {
        if (m[i][j] != m[j][i]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (verifySymmetric(m, i + 1, j, n) && verifySymmetric(m, i, j + 1, n));
        }
    }
    return 1;   
}
```

Below is a code to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int verifySymmetric(int m[20][20], int i, int j, int n) {
    if (!((n == i) || (n == j))) {
       if (m[i][j] != m[j][i]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (verifySymmetric(m, i + 1, j, n) && verifySymmetric(m, i, j + 1, n));
        }
    }
    return 1;   
}
    
int main() {
    int n, r, c, m[20][20], t[20][20], flag, i, j;
    i = j = 0;

    printf("Enter matrix order >> ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\nEnter the elements \n");

    for (r = 0; r < n; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            printf("m[%d][%d]: ", r + 1, c + 1);
            scanf("%d", &m[r][c]);
        }
    }

    for (r = 0; r < n; r++)                  
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)          
            t[c][r] = m[r][c]; 

    flag = verifySymmetric(m, i, j, n);

    if (flag == 1)
        printf("Matrix is symmetric ");
    if (flag == 0)
        printf("Matrix is not symmetric ");

    return 0;
}
```

My main concern is about the line

```
return (verifySymmetric(m, i + 1, j, n) && verifySymmetric(m, i, j + 1, n));
```

The program seem to work but I noticed that many m[row][column] is printed when I run the code. Something like this

```
Enter the elements
m[1][1]: m[1][2]: m[1][3]: m[1][4]: m[1][5]: m[1][6]: m[1][7]: m[1][8]: m[1][9]: m[1][10]: m[1] 
[11]: m[1][12]: m[1][13]: m[1][14]: m[1][15]: m[1][16]: m[1][17]: m[1][18]: m[1][19]: m[1][20]: 
m[1][21]: m[1][22]: m[1][23]: m[1][24]: m[1][25]: m[1][26]: m[1][27]: m[1][28]: m[1][29]: m[1] 
[30]: m[1][31]: m[1][32]: m[1][33]: m[1][34]: m[1][35]: m[1][36]: m[1][37]: m[1][38]: m[1][39]: 
 m[1][40]: m[1][41]: m[1][42]: m[1][43]: m[1][44]: m[2][1]: m[2][2]: m[2][3]: m[2][4]: m[2][5]: 
 m[2][6]: m[2][7]: m[2][8]: m[2][9]: m[2][10]: m[2][11]: m[2][12]: m[2][13]: m[2][14]: m[2][15]: 
 m[2][16]: m[2][17]: m[2][18]: m[2][19]: m[2][20]: m[2][21]: m[2][22]: m[2][23]: m[2][24]:
```

What would be wrong with the function?

What would be another approach?

**Edit**

This is not a good approach, using recursion for a function like this, but I was curious about it and couldn't find an example in the internet. It is basically for learning purposes.

I am using Visual Studio Code and the strange behavior described above is when I click to Run Code two times. Running once, it runs as I expected, printing `Enter matrix order >>` , but once I click it for the second time without entering the matrix order, the misbehavior happens.

Comment: Why in the world would you use recursion for this?  To make it slower and less clear?  Just use a nested loop.  Recursion is inappropriate for this problem.  There is no need for a stack.  And why is it using additional storage?  A properly coded symmetric matrix check is a nested loop whose body is a simple `if` statement that returns false for a mismatch.

Comment: @TomKarzes Using recursion for this example does not make sense, but I was curious about it and couldn't find an example in the internet. It is basically for learning purposes.

Comment: It's unclear to me what misbehavior you are asking about.  How did you run the program, what was the input you presented, and what did you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work but it is very inefficient as the recursive approach will cause many redundant comparisons. The time complexity is **O(n<sup>4</sup>)** instead of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

You reason you get this misleading output is you prompt for each matrix value to `stdout`, but the input is read from a file and not echoed to `stdout`.

Here is a simpler non-recursive approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int verifySymmetric(int m[20][20], int n) {
    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < r; c++) {
            if (m[r][c] != m[c][r])
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
    
int main() {
    int n, m[20][20];

    printf("Enter matrix order >> ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 1 || n > 20) {
        printf("invalid dimension %d\n", n);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter the elements\n");

    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
            if (scanf("%d", &m[r][c]) != 1) {
                printf("missing input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (verifySymmetric(m, n)) {
        printf("Matrix is symmetric\n");
    else
        printf("Matrix is not symmetric\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If for some reason the implementation is required to be recursive, here is a modified version without redundant comparisons:

```
int verifySymmetric(int m[20][20], int i, int j, int n) {
    if (j == n) {
        return 1;
    } else
    if (i < j) {
        return (m[i][j] == m[j][i]) && verifySymmetric(m, i + 1, j, n);
    } else {
        return verifySymmetric(m, 0, j + 1, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your point is very important, I didn't noticed that. I actually did the non-recursive approach, but using recursion was the problem.  I wonder if there's no way to keep the complexity O(n^2). Perhaps, something to do about the line `return (verifySymmetric(m, i + 1, j, n) && verifySymmetric(m, i, j + 1, n));`

Comment: There must be some other explanation for your observations, possibly some side-effect of the terminal emulation in *Visual Studio Code* on your platform. I posted a modified recursive implementation.

Comment: The complexity is still O(n^4) or O(n^2)?

Comment: @欲しい未来: no, the complexity of the modified recursive function is O(n*n) with the same number of comparisons as the nested loops.